# Is there an easy way to use gmail SMTP server with WAMP / XAMP? locally using mail()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, email

A lot of the posts I found were outdated.
the php.ini file allows you to auth using:

auth_username
auth_password

So I've tried using this in my php.ini:

```
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port = 465
auth_username = email@gmail.com
auth_password = password
```

restart wamp server, and nothing. I can't even debug it because it just hangs/I don't get a response to jquery ajax...
php file:

```
$return = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

echo $return;
```

js script:

```
btn.click( function() {
    jQuery.ajax( {
        type: "POST",
        url: form.attr( 'action' ),
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            alert(data);
        }
    } );
} );
```

nothing comes back, the console doesn't even log one line, so it just hangs/never returns.

**UPDATE:**
The php doesn't hang, it just takes a long time to timeout.
and it says I failed to connect to smtp server. I just left the page there long enough for it to return.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-from-php-page

Comment: Am I stuck with using extensions/other classes to get it to work? basic php install will not work?

Comment: trying to avoid using pear, phpmailer, fakemail, etc.

Answer (score 0):

not long before,I have the same problem as you!finally,I solve this with two methods.
1. using PHPMailer,you can see this post:http://www.web-development-blog.com/archives/send-e-mail-messages-via-smtp-with-phpmailer-and-gmail/
2.you can try set the smtp in php script,using "ini_set()".